# How to interpret this numpy corrcoef output

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, correlation

I am trying to calculate the correlation between two time series. I tried the below code

```
time1 = np.arange(0,1000,1).reshape((-1,1))
slope1 = 15
slope2 = 3
amp=1000

line1 = time1*slope1+amp
line2=time1*(0.5)+amp/10

corr=np.corrcoef(x=line1,y=line2,rowvar = False)
```

The output was

```
corr = [[1. 1.][1. 1.]]
```

I had expected that correlation would be much smaller than 1 since the slope of the two lines are different. Why is the correlation shown to be 1 ?

Answer (score 1):

Although the slope is very different you can think of correlation as something that ignores scale and looks for direction of travel. When one of your variables goes up by amount `x1` the other goes up by an amount `x1*k` where `k` is a constant so they are perfectly correlated (they always behave the same in relation to one another).

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the correlation as in the R^2 of Excel, you can use something like this (already made it for my work):

```
def correlation(Measure, Fit):
    """Calculates the correlation coefficient R^2 between the two sets
       of Y data provided. Logically, in order for the result to have a sense
       you want both Y arrays to have been created from the same X array."""

    Mean = np.mean(Measure)
    s1 = 0
    s2 = 0
    Size = np.size(Measure) # identical to np.size(Fit)

    for i in range(0, Size):
        s1 += (Measure[i] - Fit[i]) ** 2
        s2 += (Measure[i] - Mean) ** 2
    Rsquare = 1 - s1/s2
    return Rsquare
```

And I removed them for readability but you can surround this with various precautions and error messages, for example when both arrays don't have the same size or contain NANs.

Edit: the formula used comes from the coefficient of determination article on Wikipedia.
[image]